# Cómo mover el background usando JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Necesito saber como puedo mover el `background` de una imagen con `jquery` una cierta cantidad de pixeles y que este se vaya sumando con el que ya tiene. Lo ideal seria cargar una imagen larga que contiene el movimiento de una imagen.

lo que estoy tratando de hacer es lo siguiente:

```js
$('#btn-left').click(function(){
  $('.content-rotate-img').css('background-position', '0px 493px');
});
$('#btn-right').click(function(){
  $('.content-rotate-img').css('background-position', '0px 0px');
});
```

```css
.content-rotate-img {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 3px solid grey;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    background: url(https://image.ibb.co/eE1mRT/film.png);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.content-right-btn {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -28px;
    font-size:30px;
    transition:.3s;
}
.content-left-btn{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -28px;
    font-size:30px;
    transition:.3s;
}

.content-btn {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" />

<!--Inicio de Código--->
<div class="content-rotate-img">
            <div class="content-btn">
                <div class="content-left-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" id="btn-left"><i class="fa fa-repeat" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                </div>
                <div class="content-right-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" id="btn-right"><i class="fa fa-undo" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: ¿Que es lo que haz intentado? Agrega el código con lo que llevas al momento.

Comment: necesitamos mas información para comprender mejor la pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La propiedad `transition` debe ir en el `div` que tiene la imagen de fondo

Para cambiar la posición de la imagen de fondo puedes sumarle o restarle pixeles según sea el caso, para no terminar con números enormes puse un máximo para los offsets que si llegan al límite causan un efecto de reset.

Lo interesante de esto es que como `background-repeat` tiene por defecto la propiedad de `repeat` obtenemos el efecto de carrusel, hasta que llega al límite

```js
var divHeight = $('.content-btn').innerHeight();
var maxScroll = 1919;
var currentHeight = 0;

$('#btn-left').click(function() {
  if (currentHeight > maxScroll) {
    currentHeight = 0;
  } else {
    currentHeight += divHeight;
  }
  $('.content-rotate-img').css('background-position', '0px ' + currentHeight + 'px');
});
$('#btn-right').click(function() {
  if (currentHeight < (maxScroll * -1)) {
    currentHeight = 0;
  } else {
    currentHeight -= divHeight;
  }
  $('.content-rotate-img').css('background-position', '0px ' + currentHeight + 'px');
});
```

```css
.content-rotate-img {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 3px solid grey;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  background: url(https://image.ibb.co/eE1mRT/film.png);
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition: background-position 1s linear;
}

.content-right-btn {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -28px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.content-left-btn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -28px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.content-btn {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" />

<!--Inicio de Código--->
<div class="content-rotate-img">
  <div class="content-btn">
    <div class="content-left-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-success" id="btn-left"><i class="fa fa-repeat" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="content-right-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-success" id="btn-right"><i class="fa fa-undo" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias, esta era la solución que buscaba.

Comment: De nada @Dan784 veo que eres nuevo en el sitio, aprovecho para darte la bienvenida te invito a terminar el [tour] y te dejo un par de links para ayudar a guiarte en el sitio. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), [ask], [answer]